# How to record the value of a cell in Google Sheets to another cell?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

As the title states, I'm trying to create a script to record the values of a specified cell, along with the date, into a column of other cells. I only want it to record for 10 instances before overriding from the top of the column. The issue I'm facing has to do with the cell with the value to be recorded, since my current script will edit that cell by adding values to it. So lets say the cell I want recorded is A1, and the cell adding to it is B1. I need the recorded results to be in C1:C10. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us your current script and an example (formatted table in your question) of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Whenever possible, try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way